# Create X shape by conditionally printing 'x's in a loop

Tags: php, loops, shapes

This is my desired Out put:
Im unable to get this I have tried many times but in vain so thats why I'm asking

```
  x               x  
    x           x    
      x       x      
        x   x         
          x          
        x   x        
      x       x      
    x           x    
  x               x
```

But I'm Getting this

```
  x                x  
    x            x    
      x        x      
        x    x        
          xx          
          xx          
        x    x        
      x        x      
    x            x    
  x                x  



for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
{
    echo  str_repeat("&nbsp;&nbsp;",$i);
    echo  "x".str_repeat("&nbsp;&nbsp;",5-$i)."". str_repeat("&nbsp;&nbsp;",5-$i)."x".str_repeat("&nbsp;&nbsp;",$i)."<br>";
}

for($i=5;$i>=1;$i--)
{

    echo  str_repeat("&nbsp;&nbsp;",$i);
    echo  "x".str_repeat("&nbsp;&nbsp;",5-$i)."". str_repeat("&nbsp;&nbsp;",5-$i)."x".str_repeat("&nbsp;&nbsp;",$i)."<br>";
}
```

ANY one can help to solve it?

Comment: Because your loops are over lapping on one integer.

Comment: What is the goal of this?

Comment: homework. can you please help me rather than to unvote

Comment: You need to write a line between the loops with just a single `x` in the middle. And you need to adjust the spacing on the rest of the lines to match that.

Comment: My desired out but is the first one

Comment: please post as answer and  I dont know why people are voting it as bad?

Comment: People are downvoting because it's homework & it shows lack of research into resolving the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in one loop, just calculate one half (eg. left) and mirror it to the other side (except for center ofc)

```
$size = 9;
$space = "&nbsp;&nbsp;";

$center = ceil($size/2);
$maxPost = abs($center - $size);
for ($i=0; $i<$size; $i++) {
    $post = abs($center + $i - $size);
    $pre = $maxPost - $post;

    echo str_repeat($space,$pre);
    echo "x ";
    echo str_repeat($space, $post);

    if ($post > 0) {
        echo str_repeat($space, $post-1);
        echo "x ";
    }
    echo str_repeat($space, $pre) . "<br>";
}
```

See it [here](http://3v4l.org/Wbn39):

```
x               x  
  x           x    
    x       x      
      x   x         
        x          
      x   x        
    x       x      
  x           x    
x               x
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine all the `str_repeats` that are adjacent to each other, and do some arithmetic simplification. Then you need to add an extra space between the `x`'s in the arms, and write a line with a single `x` in the middle.

```
for($i=1;$i<=4;$i++)
{
    echo  str_repeat("&nbsp;",2*$i)."x".str_repeat("&nbsp;",19 - 4*$i)."x<br>";
}
echo str_repeat("&nbsp;", 10) . "x<br>";
for($i=4;$i>=1;$i--)
{
    echo  str_repeat("&nbsp;",2*$i)."x".str_repeat("&nbsp;",19 - 4*$i)."x<br>";
}
```

There's also no need for `&nbsp;` after the second `x`.

Output:

```
  x               x
    x           x
      x       x
        x   x
          x
        x   x
      x       x
    x           x
  x               x
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
{
    echo  str_repeat("&nbsp;&nbsp;",$i);
    if($i==5)
    {
        echo  "x"."<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo  "x".str_repeat("&nbsp;&nbsp;",5-$i)."". str_repeat("&nbsp;&nbsp;",5-$i-1)."&nbsp;x".str_repeat("&nbsp;&nbsp;",$i)."<br>";
    }   
}

for($i=4;$i>=1;$i--)
{
        echo  str_repeat("&nbsp;&nbsp;",$i);
        echo  "x".str_repeat("&nbsp;&nbsp;",5-$i)."". str_repeat("&nbsp;&nbsp;",5-$i-1)."&nbsp;x".str_repeat("&nbsp;&nbsp;",$i)."<br>";
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
  x               x  
    x           x    
      x       x      
        x   x        
          x
        x   x        
      x       x      
    x           x    
  x               x
```

Comment: I added the same condition in the second one but used instead of x i used <br> So it gave me the exact output.

Comment: Your output isn't symmetrical, you have an extra space to the left of the center `x`. But when I run your code, I get an extra space to the right of it.

Comment: i think i have to add `&nbsp` in `echo  "&nbsp;x"."<br>";` . see the update and check now.

Comment: Now you have an extra space on both sides. There are two spaces between the center `x` and the ones above and belowit, but only one space between all the other `x`s and their neighbors.

Comment: check again i have made some more changes.